# C++ - Creating folder method

Tags: c++, winapi, null, directory, case

I have the following method in C++:

In case the folder already exists, the correct message is displayed on the screen.  However, if the folder does NOT exist, nothing is displayed on the screen, that is, the part identified by case NULL is not executed.  How can I solve this problem?

In other words, how can I get the code after the case NULL to run if the folder does not exist?

Comment: I've used `PathIsDirectory(...)` to check if a directory exists before, though admittedly it does expose you to potential race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec say that as long as CreateDirectory succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

[CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So why don't you use an *else* to the *if clause* to print that

At max you can use a *default* in your switch to print

"There was some error".

Since the switch only executes in case of an error

Answer (score 2):

First, if the folder does not exist, `CreateDirectory()` will probably succeed and return a non-zero value, so the `if` condition will return `false` and you will never get to the `switch` statement.

Second, `GetLastError()` does as advertised: it returns the last error. If `CreateDirectory()` does not raise an error, it will return whatever was the last error set by any other function. Checking for `NULL` is not very useful.